# Fill a HDD with charcter 0

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pywin32

I am writing a program to `fill a HDD with junk` and was wondering what might be the best approach at this that will use less computer resources and time.

I have a simple `wx` interface to chose the drive letter other then the Windows drive and a start and stop button.

The approach I took was to generate `txt` files of `1MB` string (`character 0 multiplied`) using `20 threads`.
Each wile is named based on a random string combined with microtime.
Once all threads end (`try` write `except` ran out of space), the main thread opens `20 new threads` that write just `one character` to a single file each till they can't do it any more.

I know it might seem silly, but I could not think of something else.

I am doing this to fill a HDD before sending it back to get a replacement.

I know there are programs that can do this. 
I just wanted to do it myself for the learning experience.

**Can anyone suggest a better way to achieve this on any windows?**

I want to build it as a desktop program.

The main scope is to have the ability to stop the procedure at any time or add limits to how much space to fill.

Comment: FWIW, I believe it would be better to fill it with random noise than a bunch of zeroes.

Comment: keep in mind that data has written once (even wiped after) can be repaired with special equipment as well.

Comment: @triclosan There have been extended discussions about this subject, and common sense seems to be that it is quite impossible nowadays.

Comment: @glglgl in general - yes. And you are right such discussion is not in scope of the current topic. But according to physical principles how data is stored on HDD it's quite possible.

Comment: @triclosan: i guess if you wish to do it, an electromagnet and than a hammer would do the trick? or is it still possible to retrieve data from a harddisk, once it has been smashed to pieces?

Comment: If you buy a HDD and return it as it starts to develop issues. Think the company will accept an envelope filled with pieces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the built in (in Windows that is) format command with some parameters will do exactly what you want.

```
format e: /fs:NTFS /p:2
```

See also http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/ht/write-zeros-format-command.htm for more info.

Comment: Agree with you. this can be easily launched using the subprocess python module.

Comment: Is there a way to monitor progress to show a progressbar and a way to stop if needed? Also how would I achieve this without the built in feature? I want to build it into a program I can use on any windows version not just Vista+.

Comment: No progress. It's done...when it's done. To stop it you could try CTRL+C but I doubt it would work. You shouldn't bother with any windows version before Vista. They are all very depricated.